# How can i check the index length in long[] array?

Tags: c#

For example i have a long[] x
And im doing:

```
for (int i=0; i<x.length;x--)
{
}
```

I know that in x for example i have 30 indexs cells.
How can i loop over the cells(indexs) in the x array and find on each cell the length of it and also to get/show the numbers in each cell.

If in x[0] there is 232 
And in x[1] there is 21
And so on...

I want to display 232,21,....etc
And then i want to check that if x[i].length is above 0 do...
But there is no x[i].length

So how do i do it ?

---

I did:

```
public long GetHistogramMaximum(long[] histogram)
        {
            long result = 0;
            long count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
            {
                if (histogram[i] > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(histogram[i].ToString());
                    break;
                }

            }

            return result;




        }
```

And its working but each time its showing me the number twice why the messagebox is working twice each time ?
If in the first array the number is 33454 then i see the messagebox once and then once again. Whats wrong here ? I want it to show me the number only once each time.

Its like repeating each number and show it once and then once again and only then moving to the next one.

EDIT **

Maybe the problem its showing the number twice each time have something to do with the scroll event im using ?

```
void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
            myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = counter - 1;//list_of_histograms.Count-1;
            long[] tt = list_of_histograms[myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value];
            histogramControl1.DrawHistogram(tt);
            long res = GetTopLumAmount(tt, 1000);
            long max = GetHistogramMaximum(tt);
            if (res > -1)
            label24.Text = (res / 1000.0).ToString();
            setpicture(myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value);
            this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
        }
```

For some reason its getting to the scroll and do everything here again. Twice in a row.
What can be the problem ?

Comment: Do you want to know if the value bigger than 0 or if how many digit?
If the value ask: x[i]>0

Comment: You probably need a class/struct to hold this additional data (`length`), because a long array is simply a list of numbers.

Comment: The "length of a cell" doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `long[]` basically holds a number of `long` values. Doing `x[i].length` is invalid, because a `long` does not have a property `length`. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

```
long[] x = {1,2,3} ;
x.length; //this is valid because you are querying the length / count of the array
x[0].length; //this is invalid because 1 does not have a property length
```

**EDIT**

Your loop counter will be the index. So,

```
for (int i =0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
   //check for maximum, when you find it
   Console.WriteLine("The maximum value is " + x[i]);
   Console.WriteLine("The maximum value is present at index " + i);
}
```

Comment: Another thing if i wanted to display the index of the maximum ? Now im displaying the number inside the maximum index but if i want to display the index ? For example if its in myNumber[232] the number is 45 and its the maximum so display 232 and not 45.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do something based on the values in the array.:

```
for (int i=0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
   // print the number to the screen.
   Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
   if (x[i] > 0) {
      // do something else.
   }
}
```

I'm not sure what you meant by x--, but that's probably wrong from your description.

Comment: His question shows that he already is using the Length property of the array in his for loop.

Comment: Im using Length on the array that will give me the number of indexs in the array. for example 30 cells. I want to find how many numbers  ihave in each cell. For example in x[0] = 21 so i want to get the 21 and if in x[1] there is the number 34 so i want to find and get the 34. i < x.Length will give me just the list or number of indexs in the x array inside the loop i want to take out from each cell/index the content the number inside.

Comment: Michael x is just an array. Like long[] myNumbers and then in myNumbers i have 30 indexs so as you did i loop over the array myNumbers and now inside the loop i want to get from each index the number inside. there are 30 places/indexs in the myNumbers array.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael says, you can find the length of the *array* via x.Length. In C#, x.Length (where x is an array) will return a 32-bit integer that represents the *total* number of elements across all dimensions. You only have a 1D array here, so that should be sufficient for what you're trying to achieve.

If you're also after the value stored in the array, the value is called as:

```
x[i];
```

So, in an example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
}
```

... would display the value in the array in your console.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yes Ancallan i just dont understand why its showing me the value twice i edited my question in the begnning above.

Comment: The code that you're showing us here (along with the modifications that Fumble suggested) should only show you the MessageBox once per element. I can't see anything that would cause it to duplicate the MessageBox. Is it possible that you're duplicating numbers themselves in your array elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it to a string and get the length property.

```
   x[i].ToString().Length
```

Although if you want to check if the length is above zero, then surely just the presence of a value proves this?

Answer (score 0):

Your function has a terrible problem:

```
    public long GetHistogramMaximum(long[] histogram)
    {
        long result = 0;
        long count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
        {
            if (histogram[i] > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(histogram[i].ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This way, you check the values in your array.
When i=0, it checks x[i]. So, 33454 (the value you gave in x[0]) is greater than 0, it shows the number and "break;", so it stops the "for" and do what's next: it returns the result variable that is never modified.
So variables result and count are useless in your code.

Rewrite with something that way for getting the maximum in your array:

```
    public long GetHistogramMaximum(long[] histogram)
    {
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < histogram.Length; i++)
        {
            if (histogram[i] > result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} is greater than {1}", histogram[i], result);
                result = histogram[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Fumble still the messagebox.show is popup twice on each number.

Comment: MessageBox.Show is the original method or you reimplemeted it ? In both case, where is your GetHistogramMaximum() called ? Your numbers are displaying like "1, 1, 2, 2" or "1, 2, 1, 2" ?